# Unknown Component

Tags: components, identification

I have never seen a component like these. The markings say "1UL25" or "10L25" on the first line and "++" followed by a "Z" in a circle with black lines coming out of the sides. Sorry the picture is a bit blurry, it is the best I can do.

[image: Unknown components]

What are they? I have searched around but haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: Tantalum capacitors. 1 and 10 uF, 25V. Polarised like electrolytics, so connect "++" to +ve voltage.

Answer (score 4):

These are tantalum capacitors.

I'm not positive, but I would assume that these are 1uF and 10uF, both with a 25V rating.

Tantalums are polarized, hence the "++" one one leg.

---

Oops, looks like I left the same info as @BrianDrummond's comment. Sorry Brian! If you post it as an answer then I'll delete this one.

Comment: No worries, you took the time to make it a proper answer.